# Extending the term "series-reduced" to graphs in general

Tags: graph-theory

A series-reduced tree is defined as a tree with no vertices of degree 2. The word "reduced" suggests that there is a process for reducing trees that have vertices of degree 2. It seems to me that this process would be to replace any vertex chain with a single edge. For example, all path graphs with more than 2 vertices would be reduced to $P_2$. Is there a name for this process? If so, I can't seem to find it.

Also, I can't find anything about series-reduced graphs in general, even though the definition can be easily extended. One could define a series-reduced graph as a graph with no vertices of degree 2. Similarly, I can imagine a process for reducing graphs by replacing any vertex chain with a single edge. Although, I can see problems with extending this to graphs because I'm not sure how a cycle graph would be reduced. Would it reduce to the null graph? Is my extension to graphs in general valid, or are there problems with it I didn't anticipate?

Has this all been established and I just don't know the correct terminology?

Comment: The reverse process of what you describe is known as subdivision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing. You might also be interested in graph minors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor. Perhaps what you want is a shallow minor?

Comment: @BobKrueger I don't know why you only mentioned subdivision when the article defines smoothing, which is what I was looking for. I don't think graph minors are relevant. So now all I want to know is if there is a term for smoothing out a graph until it is series-reduced, and whether or not $C_1$ can be "smoothed out" to the null graph.